# Retrieve macro definition code

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Say I have defined a macro function, and for some reason (e.g. a mistake), I deleted the code. I still have the macro though.

How can I retrieve the code I used to define it ?

To define the macro, I just executed:

```
%macro(param1,param2);
my code
%mend;
```

Comment: Did you define the macro with the `Source` option specified?

Comment: How do you have the macro without the code?  Did you store a compiled version into a macro catalog?

Comment: I updated my question to clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you defined the macro with the `source` option specified and in a library you can retrieve it with the following:

```
 %copy MACRO_NAME / source;
```

Official SAS answer, see original link below:

There is no way to retrieve the original source code from a stored compiled macro. You must always save the original code in another file so that you can modify it later.

Starting with `SAS® 9.1`, there is a new `SOURCE` option for the `%MACRO` statement. When used with the existing `STORE` option, the `SOURCE` option combines and stores the source of the compiled macro.

The compiled macro code becomes an entry in a `SAS` catalog in a permanent `SAS` data library. The compiled macro and the source code are stored together in the same `SASMACR` catalog. The `SOURCE` option requires that the `STORE` option and the `SAS` option `MSTORED` be set. You can use the `SAS` option `SASMSTORE=` to identify a permanent `SAS` data library. You can store a macro or call a stored compiled macro only when the `SAS` option `MSTORED` is in effect.

Note: The source code that is saved by the `SOURCE` option begins with the `%MACRO` keyword and ends with a semicolon following the `%MEND` statement. Now that you have a way to store the source code with the `SOURCE` option, you also need a way to retrieve this information. The answer is the new `%COPY` statement, which copies specified items from a `SAS` macro library.

For example:

```
libname test 'c:\';
options mstored sasmstore=test;  

%macro test(arg) / store source des="test of the source option";
  %put arg = &arg;
  data one;
    x=1;
    run;
%mend test;

%copy test / source;
```

Source:
http://support.sas.com/kb/22/352.html

Comment: So in short, no :). Thanks for the great answer, I really like this source option.

Comment: To be practical there is still a way to damage control though, it's to set all the log options to show a maximum of details, execute the macro with simple parameters that won't make it fail, and rebuild it from it from what we see there.

Comment: use a data step with INFILE pointing to the catalogue entry of the macro and dump a few records to the SAS log using the LIST; statement

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the `SOURCE` option and your macro is relatively basic you could try using the MPRINT and SYMBOLGEN to get the log with the code but if you have conditional logic it'll be hard to recreate the code for sure.

```
options mprint symbolgen;
%my_macro(param1, param2);
```

Comment: Cool, I was just commenting something similar on your other answer.

Comment: One other thing, to avoid this, macros that are being used I save in a folder and add that to my autoexec options instead.

Comment: Can you tell me how do I add to autoexec ? I'm still quite new at SAS

Comment: Well, for starters, SO is actually bad for getting SAS help :), communities.sas.com is much better and has SAS employees who will answer questions, including the developers. Plus less restrictions on what's a 'good' question, though a bad question will still get some.

Comment: Also, in general, searching any topic on lexjansen.com will bring up user papers for the last 30+ years so there's a lot of info on there. This is a good one on autoexec and setting up reusable macros.http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/267-30.pdf

Comment: I wouldn't say SO is bad for SAS, I know you're just a handful of SAS active answerers here but the answers to my questions have always been top notch, patient and fast and I'm very grateful. That being said I get your point and thanks a lot for these pointers!

Comment: Lack of history. All of your questions have answers already on SAS Community and it goes back further than SO.